# Converting strings to timespans, $PSItem in 'switch'?

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of strings, in the form of:

> '3m 36s', '24m 38s', '59s'

, to be converted to timespans. My current "solution" is:

```
'3m 36s', '24m 38s', '59s' |ForEach-Object {

    $s = 0
    $m = 0
    $h = 0
    $PSItem.Split(' ') |ForEach-Object {

        $item = $PSItem
        switch ($PSItem[-1])
        {
            's'
            {
                $s = $item.TrimEnd('s')
            }
            'm'
            {
                $m = $item.TrimEnd('m')
            }
            'h'
            {
                $h = $item.TrimEnd('h')
            }
            Default
            {
                Write-Error 'Ooops...' -ErrorAction Stop
            }
        }
    }

    $timespan = New-TimeSpan -Hours $h -Minutes $m -Seconds $s
    # ToString() is used just to get some easy to read output
    $timespan.ToString()
}
```

While it seems to work for me, I have two issues with the above:

1. Is the general approach

> ForEach -> Split(' ') -> ForEach -> switch

OK-ish? Are there any alternative/better ways of doing the conversion?

2. I tried using $PSItem in the switch

It seems that the switch construct has it's "own pipeline"

```
# $item = $PSItem
switch ($PSItem[-1])
{
    's'
    {
        $PSItem
    }
}
```

-- in the above $PSItem evaluates to 's'(, 'm', the value matched). What is actually going on? (internaly?)

Comment: Yes, `switch` is a looping construct in PowerShell, take a look at some details [here](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Basic/Switch-is-a-looping-construct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take one `ForEach` loop out of things by performing that loop with the `Switch` command. Here's what I'd end up with:

```
'3m 36s', '59s', '24m 38s' |%{
    $TSParams = @{}
    Switch($_.Split()){
        {$_[-1] -eq 's'}{$TSParams.Add('Seconds', ([int]$_.trim('s')))}
        {$_[-1] -eq 'm'}{$TSParams.Add('Minutes', ([int]$_.trim('m')))}
        {$_[-1] -eq 'h'}{$TSParams.Add('Hours', ([int]$_.trim('h')))}
    }
    New-TimeSpan @TSParams
}
```

For each string it creates an empty hashtable, then loops through each item of the `Split()` method, adding the appropriate time to the hashtable. Then it splats that to the `New-TimeSpan` command, and moves to the next item in the `ForEach` loop. I tried it locally and had some issues initially when the numbers did not cast as an int, and it tried to convert them to a DateTime, which is why I type cast them in the above code.

Comment: Thanx Mad, I keep forgetting that splatting often makes stuff quite a bit prettier